# Windows.parent doesn't work properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have an overlay using jquery UI which lets the user to log in, when the submit button is hit and the login is successful, the overlay still remains - why might this be? The following code should work but doesn't...

> window.parent.location.href =
>   "index";

Comment: What errors do you get? Is the parent on the same domain as the popup?

Comment: No errors, but the new page sometimes loads in the popup window. It's all on a local server, Netbeans + Tomcat.

Comment: If the popup was opened via `window.open` then use `window.opener` to access it.

Answer (score 0):

try not using parent but top, i have done the same thing in one of my projects and got this error i just used top.

E.G

`top.location.href = "index";`